# preventing duplicates when inserting nodes to treeview control

Tags: c#, treeview, tree-nodes

I want to create a hierarchical view of strings based on first two characters.

If the strings are:
AAAA,AAAA,BBDD,AABB,AACC,BBDD,BBEE

I want to reate a treeview that looks like this:

```
AA  
  AAAA  
  AABB
  AACC 
BB
  BBDD
  BBEE
```

I currently have some code that looks like this (inside a loop over the strings):

```
    TreeNode pfxNode;

    if (treeView1.Nodes[pfx]!=null) {
        pfxNode = treeView1.Nodes[pfx];
    }
    else {
        pfxNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(pfx);
    }

    if (!pfxNode.Nodes.ContainsKey(string)) {
        pfxNode.Nodes.Add(string, string + " some info");
    }
```

For some reason this ends up with multiple "AA" nodes at the top level.
What am I missing?

please no pre-filtering of strings I want to be able to check if a specific treenode exists based on its key.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else {
    pfxNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(pfx);
}
```

There's your mistake, you are forgetting to set the key of the tree node.  So the next ContainsKey() won't find it.  Fix:

```
    pfxNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(pfx, pfx);
```

Comment: This is definately what I was missing. I expected that pfx would also become the key when a single string is provided. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var q = from s in arr
        group s by s.Substring(0, 2) into g
        select new
        {
            Parent = g.Key,
            Children = g.Select (x => x).Distinct()
        };

foreach (var item in q)
{
    var p = new TreeNode(item.Parent);
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(p);
    foreach (var item2 in item.Children)
        p.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(item2));
}
```

Comment: although the answer provided by @Hans Passant solved my Problem I am still interested in your answer as well. This is LINQ syntax - right? could you provide some details on how this should work ? also is there any performance or other advantage to this syntax?

Comment: also I was not able to run add this code to my program, it does not seem to know what var is and keeps saying that many ;'s are missing along this text block. should I install something to make this work ?

Comment: @epeleg You need .NET >= 3.5 for Linq and `var` key word to work. As for performance linq `group by` and `distinct` operation are pretty good.